# Python- unexplained behaviour of datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to understand a weird behavior when using `datetime` inside python's dictionary. Code below is written to explain. I expected that the example of variable `a` and `b` will act the same as `self.x` and `self.y`.

To be more clear: at the beginning `self.x=1`,`self.y=2`, later on `self.x=self.y`, and inside a while loop - `self.x` is getting incremented by 1. As expected, only `self.x` is reaching the value of `5`, while `self.y` remains at `2` as shown in run result below.

BUT I'm looking for an explanation why it is not happening with `a`, `b` which both increase by `datetime.timedelta(days=3)` while only `b` is was coded to be incremented.

Any explaintion why ?

```
class TBD:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
        print(self.x, self.y)
        self.run_it()

    def run_it(self):
        self.x = self.y
        z = 0
        a = {'start': datetime.datetime.now(), 'end': datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)}
        b = a

        while z < 3:
            self.x += 1

            z += 1
            b['end'] = b['end'] + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
            print(b['end'], a['end'])
            print('x=', self.x, 'y=', self.y)
```

Run results:

```
1 2
2018-05-15 16:26:58.101727 2018-05-15 16:26:58.101727
x= 3 y= 2
2018-05-18 16:26:58.101727 2018-05-18 16:26:58.101727
x= 4 y= 2
2018-05-21 16:26:58.101727 2018-05-21 16:26:58.101727
x= 5 y= 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `b = a` **does not** create a copy, and there's a fundamental difference between mutable objects like dictionaries and immutable objects like integers. *(Note this is nothing to do with datetime.)*

Comment: This isn't really specific to classes or datetimes; you could do `x = {0:1}; y = x; x[0] = 2; print(y)` and see that mutating x also mutates y.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. understood